# How to use a custom xml file to load variables to my spring.xml using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-bean

I´m trying to use a custom xml as my properties file so I can define some variables on the spring.xml file.

I searched for similar question, but the xml file had to follow a standard to be use.

Normally I would load the .properties files like this:

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:///PATH_TO_FILE\file.properties"/>
</bean>
```

So then I can inject properties to my spring.xml in variables in the form of `${variable}`.

My custom xml looks like this:

```
<configAttributes>
<attributes>
    <attribute>
        <name>NameOftheVariable</name>
        <description>Text</description>
        <value>valueIWantoToInject</value>
    </attribute>
<attributes>
```

I´m using spring-beans 2.5 and Java EE 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read xml file using any parser, I assume you are already doing it as you mentioned in your comments.

so now you have a client bean inside your spring configuration which needs the property to be injected from xml parsed values.

So, Just load that bean in spring as

```
BeanClass bean = `context.getBean(clientBeanid);
```

then set the parsed values from xml file to bean as below

```
bean.setName(parsedxmlname);
bean.setName(parsedxmldescription);
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks @karibasappa-g-c I´m am aware of the standard but the company I´m working with does not want to use the .properties file, instead use the custom xml file.

Comment: oh okie...then check with them which parser should you use as there are many xml parsers to read xml file...

Comment: They are using `javax.xml` to parse the xml file. But after they parse and save the value of the attibute I don´t see how can I inject it in the spring.xml in the placeholder of a variable

Comment: After parsing, where are the keeping those parsed value ?

Comment: They store all the values from the xml file in a class which sets all the variables and constants of the application.

Comment: then why do you need to inject again in spring xml file, you can use it from your application class right

Comment: Let me give you an example of what I´m trying to do. I have my custom xml file, I parse it , and save the value of that variable, this variable holds the URL of a web service. In my spring.xml I have bean for my client which connects to the web service, I want to be able to replace the URL value  of the client bean which the value I get from my custom xml

Comment: check the updated answer, i think it should help you !!

Comment: Just to be clear, the `bean.setName` would be name of my variable in my spring.xml file?

Comment: yes correct, in fact corresponding java class should also be there right, so get the setter from there...

Answer (score 0):

It's a two step solution

1. [Overriding PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.in/2007/06/extending-spring-propertyplaceholdercon.htmlhttp://robertmaldon.blogspot.in/2007/06/extending-spring-propertyplaceholdercon.html?m=1)
   You have to override the 
   resolvePlaceholder() where in the logic will be inserted to return the expected result
2. [Parsing the xml](http://googleweblight.com/http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/parse-xml-file-in-java-example-tutorial.html?m%3D1&ei=Q7BlMOsC&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=419&ts=1437617916&sig=AKQ9UO9Np_8qRaVg4fkQ3TAlKrGowrtdTA)
   The parser should help to read the xml to the required format and supply it to your resolvePlaceholder()